# How to get the document loaded to WebView?

Tags: .net, webview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, webclient

I want to do this

```
Uri targetUri = new Uri(Address.Text);    
WebView1.Navigate(targetUri);
string content = WebView1.GetDocument(); //How can I get the document loaded from the target Uri?
```

I have looked at the API in MSDN, but I didn't see anything noteworthy.

I suppose I can hook into `FrameNavigationStarting`, and capture the Uri and initiate a separate request via `WebClient`, but this seems like a cludgy solution to a simple problem.

I must be missing something - please help.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve that `document` which we often use like `document.getElementById('MyTextbox')`?

Comment: @Xyroid, I meant to get the response returned by the server. If it's an HTML, then I want the HTML document, JSON, then the JSON, and XML respectively etc. How can I do this? I'm new to the API.

Comment: You can communicate using javascript between webview & app.

Comment: I'm still not getting how I can get anything out of the WebView, back into the app. Eg. after I execute a javascript, how do I get that result out of the WebView? I know I can do 1 directional communication from App to WebView, but what about the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Windows 8:

You can get the WebView page content doing something like this:

```
private void webView_LoadCompleted_1(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    WebView webView = sender as WebView;

    string html = webView.InvokeScript(
        "eval",
        new string[] {"document.documentElement.outerHTML;"});

    // Here you can parse html ....
}
```

### Windows 10 Update:

`InvokeScript()` throws the following exception in Windows 10:

> An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in App1.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.

Use `InvokeScriptAsync()` instead.

XAML:

```
<WebView Source="http://kiewic.com" LoadCompleted="WebView_LoadCompleted"></WebView>
```

C#:

```
private async void WebView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    WebView webView = sender as WebView;

    string html = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync(
        "eval",
        new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });

    // TODO: Do something with the html ...
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(html);
}
```